# Compile C# Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2019

Recently I downloaded the Visual Studio 2019 Preview. When I run a c# program a program called dotnet.exe runs instead [image: What program the c# runs on]. The problem is that in the old visual studio when you ran it would compile it and open the program that it just compiled. When I tried to use the old Visual Studio I had the same problem. I want a stand alone .exe compiled like how the old vs did. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer is to create a .NET Framework project, not a .NET Core project.  That will be the same as the projects you are familiar with.